# draw route with multiple markers on Google Map iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-markers

I'm new to iPhone development, in my application I want to draw route between two points and show the multiple markers on my route. Now I'm done with the Route between two points but I don't know how to draw multiple markers on my route. So please help me to do this.

Thanks in Advance!!!

```
_markerStart = [GMSMarker new];
_markerStart.title = [[[routeDict objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"start_address"];
_markerStart.icon = newImage; //[UIImage imageNamed:@"startMarker.png"];
_markerStart.map = gmsMapView;
_markerStart.position = startPoint;

_markerFinish = [GMSMarker new];
_markerFinish.title = [[[routeDict objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"end_address"];
_markerFinish.icon = newImage; //[UIImage imageNamed:@"finishMarker.png"];
_markerFinish.map = gmsMapView;
_markerFinish.position = endPoint;
```

Here I have added start and end marker.

Comment: Have u completed only plotting markers for end points? or drawing complete Route?

Comment: yah..now I want some more on route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are completed with drawing route between two points, you will have co-ordinates for route. You can take some co-ordinates from those and draw them on Google Maps.

For drawing route you may have used `GMSPolyline`. For polyline, you must have used `GMSPath`. From path you can get co-ordinates by using method

`-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinateAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index`

[GMSPath Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_path.html#a972bbf771518e98cbed54bbb3fb53255)

You can use these co-ordinates to plot the marker on route. [GMSMarkers Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker)

Check this code (here gmsPath as `GMSPath`) **EDIT**:

```
//GMSPath *gmsPath;
//NSString *title;
for (int i = 0; i < [gmsPath count]; i++) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [gmsPath coordinateAtIndex: i];
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:location];
    marker.title = title;
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_img.png"];
    marker.map = self.mapView;
}
```

This will plot marker for each co-ordinate.

Comment: for loop condition gives error : invalid operands to binary expression